# How to append multi dimensional array using for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to `append` to a multi-dimensional array.

This is what I have done so far:

```
arr=[[]]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(5):
        arr[i].append(i*j)
        print i,i*j


print arr
```

This is my expected output:

> `[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,2,4,6,8],[0,3,6,9,12],[0,4,8,12,16],[0,5,10,15,20],[0,6,12,18,24],[0,7,14,21,28],[0,8,16,24,32],[0,9,18,27,36]]`

However, I am getting this error:

> `IndexError`: list index out of range

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're forgetting to append the empty list beforehand. Thus why you get a, `IndexError` when you try to do `arr[i]`.

```
arr = []
for i in range(10):
    arr.append([])
    for j in range(5):
        arr[i].append(i*j)
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to define your initial array in the following way: `arr=[[] for i in range(10)]`, as you cannot append a value to a nonexistent array (which is what happens when `i>=1`). So the code should look like:

```
arr=[[] for i in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(5):
        arr[i].append(i*j)
        print(i,i*j)


print(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

As [others have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43291192/7256039), you need to make sure your list of lists is initially populated with ten empty lists (as opposed to just one) in order for successive elements to be `append`ed correctly.

However, I might suggest using a terser nested list comprehension instead, which avoids the problem entirely by creating the list in a single statement:

```
arr = [[i*j for j in range(5)] for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You init your `arr` as an `array` with only 1 element, so you have such an error when `i` goes greater than `0`. You can use `list comprehensive` to archive your purpose:

```
[[i * j for j in range(5)] for i in range(10)]
```